# Typescript and Material UI - pass object to createMuiTheme

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm using TypeScript along with Material UI, and I can't understand why I can't pass an object to createMuiTheme.

This works:

```
const themeConfig = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: green,
    secondary: purple,
    type: 'light'
  }
});
```

This doesn't work (!):

```
const themeObject = {
  palette: {
    primary: green,
    secondary: purple,
    type: 'light'
  }
};

const themeConfig = createMuiTheme(themeObject);
```

It tells me that palette.type = 'light' (string) is not assignable to palette.type = 'light' | 'dark' | undefined. Really don't understand.

```
Argument of type '{ palette: { primary: { 50: "#e8f5e9"; 100: "#c8e6c9"; 200: "#a5d6a7"; 300: "#81c784"; 400: "#66bb6a"; 500: "#4caf50"; 600: "#43a047"; 700: "#388e3c"; 800: "#2e7d32"; 900: "#1b5e20"; A100: "#b9f6ca"; A200: "#69f0ae"; A400: "#00e676"; A700: "#00c853"; }; secondary: { ...; }; type: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ThemeOptions'.
  The types of 'palette.type' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"light" | "dark" | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the section "Using createStyles to defeat type widening" from https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/.

You can pass the options directly as argument in createMuiTheme():

```
const themeConfig = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: green,
    secondary: purple,
    type: 'light'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's wondering, populating `createMuiTheme({})` with an object works in JS, if not TS - I just tried it to find out.

It does need an empty object to start with, and obviously it cannot be initialized as a `const`, since you're immediately going to populate it.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { blue, green, pink, yellow } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

let theme = {};
const themeObject = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: blue[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
    info: {
      main: pink[400],
    },
    warning: {
      main: yellow[900],
    },
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        body: {
          backgroundImage: `url("/background-image.jpg")`,
          backgroundAttachment: `fill`,
          backgroundSize: `cover`,
          backgroundPosition: `0 0`,
          backgroundRepeat: `no`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export default theme = createMuiTheme(themeObject);
```